# Oracle regexp_replace default replace string

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, regexp-replace

I have a simple question I cant find the answer for:

Is this:

```
regexp_replace(somecolumn, someregex)
```

The same as the following?

```
regexp_replace(somecolumn, someregex, NULL)
```

Comment: Good question. Often Oracle documentation looks like it's written by morons. Case in point - the syntax diagram for `regexp_replace` shows that the `replace_string` argument is optional, but doesn't say anywhere what the behavior is if that argument is left out. Your guess is 100% correct, but you shouldn't have to guess, that should be crystal clear in the documentation.

Comment: I agree haha, I asked this question because im running some queries I have in an oracle project, in an hsql database, and some oracle queries are not working. 
I noticed that regexp_replace(somecolumn, someregex, NULL)  doesn't work on hsqldb, but regexp_replace(somecolumn, someregex) does work, hence my question.

Comment: Would the query in hsql (whatever that is) work if you used an empty string instead? Oracle - in direct violation of the SQL standard - treats empty string the same as null; what you REALLY want in your "replace", if things were done properly, is to replace with empty string (not with "unknown value" which is what null is, more or less).

Comment: Yes, it works with an empty string! 
Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they're the same. The documentation for [REPLACE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/REPLACE.html) is more explicit about this behavior:

> If replacement_string is omitted or null, then all occurrences of search_string are removed.

But [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/REGEXP_REPLACE.html) behaves the same way. The third argument `replace_string` replaces whatever matches the pattern; if it's omitted or null, all matching parts of the string are removed.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification!